# Using Anthos to migrate workloads between GKE Cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-anthos

Any chance to migrate workloads from a `GKE Cluster` to different `GKE Cluster` using `Anthos` ? . The requirement for us is to migrate workloads from a `Public GKE Cluster` to a `Private GKE Cluster` . I see `GCP VM` is listed for `migctl` but `GKE` is not listed

[image]

https://cloud.google.com/migrate/anthos/docs/migctl-reference#migctl-source-create

We can execute the same using `velero` tool but looking for other options?